# I got a OSError when trying to rename every file in Program Files (x86)

Tags: python

I'm a beginner at python and wanted to mess around for a bit and since there is a current coronavirus outbreak I figured it would be funny to try and make a script that renames every file it can (avoiding windows errors) to coronavirus but when trying to rename everything in program files i got a wierd OSError.I never encountered this problem so far and I don't know how to fix it.(If i can)

```
import os
PRF = r"C:\Program Files (x86)"
for root in os.walk(PRF)
    os.rename(str(root) , "Coronavirus!")
```

It gives this error :

```
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: "('C:\\\\\\\\Program Files (x86)', ['Common Files', 'Internet Explorer', 'Microsoft.NET', 'Reference Assemblies', 'Windows Defender', 'Windows Mail', 'Windows Media Player', 'Windows Multimedia Platform', 'Windows NT', 'Windows Photo Viewer', 'Windows Portable Devices', 'Windows Sidebar', 'WindowsPowerShell'], ['desktop.ini'])" -> 'Coronavirus!'
```

Also in case you need to know I'm doing this on a VM

Comment: As the error message tells you, `root` is not an individual filename. `os.walk()` returns a tuple which contains lists you need to loop over.

Comment: BTW, you do realize you'll be deleting all but one file in each directory?

Comment: Oh? I didn't know that.

Comment: But that's why I'm doing this on a VM. I'm just a beginner so I might make mistakes that i don't even know about.

Comment: Rename multiple files to the same destination name -> all but the last gets deleted. (On Windows there are more cases where the rename attempt can just fail, since in-use files can't be deleted there -- as they can on UNIX, where directory entries and inodes are decoupled and the latter are reference-counted).

Comment: But at least I've learned something!

Comment: Yup! And the duplicate question I linked you to up top ("Using os.walk in Python") should help further.

Comment: Oh you're right! Last time I tried to code something like this I wanted to make a random name gen to not have this issue. Hadn't tought of that up until now!  Thanks!